# Can't remove time from datetime type with razor syntax asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, datepicker, datetime-format

I have a datetime displaying in a textbox (jquery datepicker)and I want to remove the time. Here is what I have and what I've tried with no luck.

What is commented out is what I have and below it is what I've tried.

```
 @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClassDate, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", new { @class = "date-field form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })*@
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClassDate, new { @class = "date-field form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Here is my viewmodel

```
[DisplayName("Date")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime ClassDate { get; set; }
```

This is what I see on the screen. The time doesn't drop using textboxfor and I loose boostrap formatting after I change to a editorfor element and the time still doesn't hide.

This is with textboxfor

[image]

this is with editorfor

[image]

and in javascript in document ready I have

```js
 $(".date-field").datepicker({
   minDate: 0, //sets min date to today, so user can't select anything before today
   maxDate: 30
 });
```

Comment: use ToShortDateString

Comment: or you can do this

[DataType(DataType.Date)]

public DateTime? DateProperty { get; set; }

Comment: ToShortDateString on what? I tried it on model.ClassDate but it threw an error.

Comment: for editor 
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReturnDate.ToShortDateString())
and for label 
@Html.Label(Model.ReturnDate.ToShortDateString())

Comment: You can always set the value attribute to model.ReturnDate.ToShortDateString()
`@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ReturnDate, new { @class = "date-field form-control", @readonly = "readonly" , value=model.ReturnDate.ToShortDateString()})`

Comment: Are you using MVC-5.1+? If not, then `EditorFor()` will not add html attributes (and you not using the correct syntax anyway). How are you attaching the boostrap datepicker plugin (show your script)

Comment: I've inserted the javascript above. I'm not sure which version of MVC I'm using. The one that comes with VS 2013

Comment: Add the format option format: `$(".date-field").datepicker({ format: mm/dd/yyyy', ...});`, but you will need to use `TextBoxFor()` since `EditorFor()` will not add a class name.

Comment: ok that's fine! I want to use textboxfor, not editorfor

Answer (score -2):

Simple conversion using `ToString()` will help you.

In your case following will help you.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ClassDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), new { @class = "date-field form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Comment: I get an error message in VS that says "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

Comment: if you are doing  One way binding then, Simple TextBox will do the job.

<input type="text" value="@Model.ClassDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")" readonly class="date-field form-control"/>

this should Work Now...